# Issue signing in on mobile Android Studio Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2p57.png)

My application works on both Android Studio's simulator and bluestacks emulator.

But when I export the APK to my Android tablet, my internet connection is working fine, but the login page is just stuck on signing in as is shown in the picture.

Appreciate any help and will provide any source required to assist in resolving the issue!

Here's the source code for the sign in authentication

```
   progressDialog.setMessage("Signing In...");

    progressDialog.show();

    String emailzxc = (email+"@gmail.com");
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailzxc, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        //start the profile activity

                        {Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CalenderActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("email", email);
                            startActivity(intent);}
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

`

Comment: Please provide source code of that

Comment: The source code is uploaded.

Comment: are you getting  toast message atleast  saying that "Login failed, please try again." ??

Comment: No, It's only showing the dialogue "Signing in" for the whole time.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine on Android Studio simulator but only when i build and open it in my android tablet, it's just looping the signing in dialog which is as if there was no internet connection or couldn't connect to the database

Comment: You are not responding to me sir.